# How to pass String data from PropertiesService on Google Apps Script to client code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, properties, client-server

How is the counter property read, incremented, and then written back to PropertiesServices?

Currently, that property is being logged as NaN.

server log:

```
increment
    incrementCounter
    Web App
    Oct 16, 2022, 4:20:11 PM
    0.224 s
    
Completed
Cloud logs
Oct 16, 2022, 4:20:11 PM
Info
NaN
```

client log:

```
addNote..
userCodeAppPanel:12 undefined
userCodeAppPanel:13 jkljkljkl;jkl;jklj
2849282381-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:105 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
2849282381-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:105 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at userCodeAppPanel:9:62
    at Lf (445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:92:266)
    at 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:25:132
    at Ug.V (445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:125:380)
    at Id (445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:56:477)
    at a (445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:54:52)
(anonymous) @ userCodeAppPanel:9
Lf @ 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:92
(anonymous) @ 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:25
Ug.V @ 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:125
Id @ 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:56
a @ 445342555-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:54
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    var counter = "65456456456456456456";
    var note = "";
    function addNote()
    {
      console.log("addNote..");
      note = document.getElementById("note").value;
      counter = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((success) => {
        document.getElementById("successfulClick").innerHTML = success;
      })
      .incrementCounter();
      console.log(counter);
      console.log(note);
      document.getElementById("counter").textContent = counter;
      document.getElementById("note").textContent = note;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="success"></div> <br>
  <div id="counter"></div> <br>
  <div id="row"></div> <br>
  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <input type="textarea" cols="40" rows="5" id="note" value=""/>
  <input type="button" value="addNote" onclick="addNote()" />
</body>

</html>
```

code:

```
function init() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("counter","3");
}

function incrementCounter() {
  var counter = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(counter);
  counter = parseInt(counter);
  counter++;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("counter",counter);
  Logger.log(counter);
  return counter;
}


function getUrl() {
  Logger.log("getUrl..");

  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}



function doGet(e) {
  // Logger.log("doGet..");
  init();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

From the client logs it looks like the counter in the HTML is null, and yet it was initialized with a value, if that's a correct reading of that log.

From the server logs, quite clearly the server side variable isn't a number, as it's logging NaN -- however, it should still have a value even if not a number. That property was initialized with a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your Google Apps Script side, `counte` of `var counter = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(counter);` is not declaread.

  - I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `From the server logs, quite clearly the server side variable isn't a number, as it's logging NaN -- however, it should still have a value even if not a number.`.
- In your Javascript side, `google.script.run` returns `void`. By this, `counter` is changed by `counter = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((success) => { document.getElementById("successfulClick").innerHTML = success; })`. By this, `undefined` is shown in the log of `console.log(counter);`.

  - I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `From the client logs it looks like the counter in the HTML is null, and yet it was initialized with a value, if that's a correct reading of that log.`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `incrementCounter()` as follows.

```js
function incrementCounter() {
  var counter = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("counter"); // Modified
  counter = parseInt(counter, 10);
  counter++;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("counter",counter);
  Logger.log(counter);
  return counter;
}
```

##### HTML side:

Please modify `addNote()` as follows.

```js
function addNote() {
  console.log("addNote..");
  note = document.getElementById("note").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((success) => { // Modified
    document.getElementById("successfulClick").innerHTML = success;
  })
  .incrementCounter();
  console.log(counter);
  console.log(note);
  document.getElementById("counter").textContent = counter;
  document.getElementById("note").textContent = note;
}
```

- When these modifications are reflected in your script, the tag of `successfulClick` shows the returned value from  `incrementCounter()`. And, the tag of `counter` shows `var counter = "65456456456456456456";`.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0):

what was specifically missing was handling the return value from, in the below example, `getFoo`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    var foo = "foo";
    function loadFoo(){
      foo = "bar";

    console.log(foo);

    foo = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((data) => {
        document.getElementById("foo").textContent = data;
      })
      .getFoo();

      console.log(foo);
      document.getElementById("foo").textContent = foo;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="foo">index</div>
  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <input type="button" value="loadFoo" onclick="loadFoo()" />
</body>
</html>
```

code:

```
function getFoo() {
  var foo = "baz"
  Logger.log(foo);
  return foo;
}

function getUrl() {
  Logger.log("getUrl..");
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}


function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
  htmlOutput.foo = "foo" + getFoo();
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

Explanatory notes on the mechanics of why `data` is [required](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRyxJZRlrWM) above, and how exactly that works, appreciated.